# nginx: [emerg] invalid condition "$http_user_agent"

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Trying to bypass cache for specific user agent for the urls having specific word.

What I'm doing is that I want to bypass SatelliteWP/rocket-nginx cache for the user-agent (Bingbot) if the url contains any specific word such as 'activate or deactivate'. I'm able to bypass the cache for the user-agent but for all urls. For this i used:

```
# User agent to bypass cache
if ($http_user_agent ~* "Bingbot") {
    set $rocket_bypass 0;
    set $rocket_is_bypassed "BYPASS";
   set $rocket_reason "User Agent bypass";
}
```

However, I try to use the below code for bypassing cache for the user-agent 'Bingbot' for the urls containing specific word

``````
if ($http_user_agent ~* "Bingbot" && $request_uri ~* "(activate|deactivate)") {
        set $rocket_bypass 0;
        set $rocket_is_bypassed "BYPASS";
        set $rocket_reason "User Agent and Word bypass";
    }
`````

**But after getting error:
**
nginx: [emerg] invalid condition "$http_user_agent" in /etc/nginx/rocket-nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf:177
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed


I tried but unable to reach at the solution.
``````